# Reusing android listview

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I am trying to create a listview with add button on the side as shown in the right image http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/images/android.png

Is it possible to reuse this existing layout object. If so what is it called exactly? All I can find in the default listview is simple checkboxes and other listviews without buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own listview by making an extra xml in your layout folder.

for example your make a textview and next to that textview a button, then inflate that.